# Angular: How can a "loading" animated gif be implemented in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following declaration in my AngularJS config:

```
.state('state1', {
     templateUrl: 'some_template.html',
     controller: 'chartCtrl',
     resolve: {
        chart: function(load){
             return loadChart.load();
        }
     }
})
```

The controller `chartCtrl` will only start when the `loadChart.load` function ends, therefore I cannot manage in the controller an indicator to turn on/off an animated gif . Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it in your app run config file:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(){
   loadChart.load();
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
   loadChart.end();
});
```

It's bad idea that the controller start any pre-loading, because you can't reuse it for another controllers and it needs be more controllable.

You can define it for only resolver states, for example:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){
   if(toState.resolve){
     loadChart.load();
   }
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(){
   loadChart.end();
});
```

Read more about [**State Changes Events**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

Comment: added to app.run instead of config